# Change the image in Joomla site

Tags: joomla-2.5, administration, basics

Please visit this link : http://naadiastrology.info/

On Bottom you can see "Contact address", on left of that there is a "fingerprints image".

How to change the "fingerprint" image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the name of the module, but it's definitely a custom one.

Go to the Module Manager in the Joomla backend, and search for custom modules or module that belong to the **bottom-section** position.

Open the correct one and remove the image from the textarea

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will check and let you know....

Comment: hi, i opened the module manager, and opened some modules, but i don't know where is text area? please help me....

Comment: @user2384317 - Don't just open any module. Use the filter options to narrow down the search. In the filter, select the **bottom-section** which will then display all modules that belong to that position. It's definitely a module so it **will** be there ;)

Comment: Hi,

Thanka a lot for your help, it worked....

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this image is in a Joomla **Module**.

In Joomla 2.5:

1. Login to the [administrator area](http://naadiastrology.info/administrator/) of your site
2. Select **Extensions** > **Module Manager** from the main menu
3. Look for a module in position *bottom-section* or similar - it'll probably be a *Custom HTML* module
4. In the HTML editor, replace the image.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will check and let you know....

Comment: hi, i opened the module manager, and opened some modules, but i don't know where is text area? please help me....

Comment: Hi,

Thanka a lot for your help, it worked....